# Retrieve records from pivot matching it's owner

Tags: mysql, mariadb

using latest mariaDB release, I have the following table structure (trimmed for example)

```
Table A
+--------+------+
| id     |name  |
+--------+------+
| 1      | Bob  |
| 2      | Jane |
+--------+------+

Table B
+--------+------+
| id     |city  |
+--------+------+
|      1 | abc  |
|      2 | def  |
|      3 | ghi  |
|      4 | jkl  |
+--------+------+

Pivot Table
+-----------+-----------+
| tableA_id | tableB_id |
+-----------+-----------+
|      1    |   1       |
|      1    |   3       |
|      2    |   3       |
|      2    |   4       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

is there a way to make it go from this output or will that need to be done php?

```
+--------+------+-------+
| id     |name  | city1 |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | Bob  |  abc  |
| 1      | Bob  |  ghi  |
| 2      | Jane |  ghi  |
| 2      | Jane |  jkl  |
+--------+------+-------+
```

to this:

```
+--------+------+----------+
| id     |name  | cities   |
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      | Bob  |  abc ghi |
| 2      | Jane |  ghi jkl |
+--------+------+----------+
```

using the below query currently

```
SELECT c.id, c.city1, p.id pid, p.first_name FROM city c
INNER JOIN pivot_tablet piv ON c.id = piv.city_id
INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = piv.person_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT p.id,p.first_name,group_concat(c.city1 SEPARATOR ' ') as cities, 
FROM pivot_tablet piv inner join city ON c.id = piv.city_id
INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = piv.person_id
group by p.id, p.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp (row1 int,row2 int,row3 int,row4 varchar(20),row5 int,row6 varchar(20))
insert into #temp
select * from table3 join Table1 on Table1.id=Table3.idTable1 join table2 on table2.id = table3.idtable2

select row1,row4,
row6 
= STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + t2.row6
        FROM #temp t2
        WHERE t1.row1 = t2.row1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1, 2, '')
FROM #temp t1
GROUP BY t1.row1,t1.row4